# upload file with file.io api

Tags: php, api, upload

I want upload file with [file.io](https://file.io) API by php
my code:

```
<?php


echo share('test.rar');

function share($sFile)
{   
$request = curl_init('https://file.io/?expires=1m');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => '@' . realpath($sFile)
    ));

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
Return curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
}
?>
```

and get error in output:

{"success":false,"error":400,"message":"Trouble uploading file"}

how to fix it?

Comment: i 
57/5000
I think the problem is from realpath but I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was resolved by changing the code below

```
<?php

echo share('test.rar');

function share($sFile)
{   
$cfile = new CURLFile($sFile,'file/rar','sample_name');
$request = curl_init('https://file.io/?expires=1m');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
      'file' => $cfile
    ));

curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
Return curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
}
?>
```